# Django user selects multiple images from gallery and saves it as strings in database backend

Tags: python, django, forms, image

Im trying to create a form where the user selects from a gallery of images and it saves it to the database. The code below currently renders some radio buttons in the html output. Is there anyway I can change these to images i have saved in a static directory so the user can click on images instead? Would be great if I could change what it saves in the database to what I needed instead of image urls as well. Theres lots of documentation on uploading images but not much I could find on selecting images. Im using django 1.9.7 and python 3.5

**models.py**

```
            client_choices = (('client1', 'Client 1'),
                          ('client2', 'Client 2'),
                          ('client3', 'Client 3'),
                          ('client4', 'Client 4'),
                          ('client5', 'Client 5'))

            class ClientSelect(models.Model):

                client = MultiSelectField(choices=client_choices)
```

**forms.py**

```
            from app.models import ClientSelect
            class ClientSelectForm(forms.ModelForm):
                class Meta:
                    model = ClientSelect
                    fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
            class FormWizard(SessionWizardView):
                template_name = "app/clientchoices.html"
                #define what the wizard does when its finished collecting information
                def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
                    form_data = process_form_data(form_list)

                    return render_to_response('app/about.html', {'form_data': form_data})
```

**urls.py**

```
                url(r'^clientchoices$', FormWizard.as_view([ClientSelectForm]) , name='clientchoices'),
```

**clientchoices.html**

```
            {% load staticfiles %}
            {% block content %}

            <section class="content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="fit-form-wrapper">

                        <h2>Client Choices</h2>

                            <p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>


                            {% for field in form %}
                                {{field.error}}
                            {% endfor %}

                            <form action="{% url 'clientchoices' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                            <table>
                                {{ wizard.management_form }}
                                {% if wizard.form.forms %}
                                    {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
                                    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
                                        {{ form }}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ wizard.form }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </table>
                            {% if wizard.steps.prev %}
                            <button class="btn btn-brand" name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">"First Step"</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-brand" name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">"Previous Step"</button>
                            {% endif %}

                            <input class="btn btn-brand" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                            </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>


            {% endblock %}
```

Any help is appreciated thank you

Comment: You have to customize the widget and maybe write your own widget class: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/ . As an alternative you can manually write the required HTML in your template instead of just including the form.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is there any chance you could elaborate on what widget to use or start with?